# Changing the tooltip dynamically for each record

Tags: oracle11g, oracleforms

In forms I have a block that contains name of tables. 
The column is narrow so I want to add a tooltip that contains the value for each row.
I tried to put this code in post_query

```
       :set_item_property('block1.value',tooltip_text, :block1.value);
```

but the tooltip always contains the last row's value and shows 
it for all the rows. What could be the problem here?

Comment: Great question! Thanks for asking this. I've found a solution thanks to you. ;)

Answer (score 3):

`set_item_instance_property` is the ideal way to affect a column for just specific rows of data. But, `tooltip_text` is not available for setting via `set_item_instance_property`.

What you could do, though, is put your call to `set_item_property` into a `when-new-record-instance` trigger on the block. That way it should change the tooltip each time a new record becomes the focus.

Comment: i try it but its show so small like a point and i dont see the letters in. do you have another solution?

Comment: Does the column actually have a value?

Comment: ye,each colunm have value